# Runtime error after extracting strings in Android Studio

Tags: android, string, android-studio

I was working on a project which used exclusively strings literals in the code and layout, so I extracted them to strings.xml to later localize. Unfortunately after extracting all the strings and when trying to run I get a runtime error:

```
2020-06-16 13:54:20.482 22717-22717/com.Applikation.OReels.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.Applikation.OReels.android, PID: 22717
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.Applikation.progressplay.Android.ProgressPlayApplication: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f0062
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5743)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0f0062
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:433)
        at com.Applikation.progressplay.Android.Shared.DataManager.DataManager.createServerMessage(DataManager.kt:183)
        at com.Applikation.progressplay.Android.Shared.DataManager.DataManager.<init>(DataManager.kt:33)
        at com.Applikation.progressplay.Android.Shared.DataManager.DataManager$Companion.shared(DataManager.kt:45)
        at com.Applikation.progressplay.Android.ProgressPlayApplication.onCreate(ProgressPlayApplication.kt:22)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5740)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1656) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

**DataManager.kt** Line 183:
`serverErrors.put("em_DailyDepositLimitIsBelowZero" , Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.daily_deposit_limit))`

Any help or advice would be welcome.

Comment: `at com.Applikation.progressplay.Android.Shared.DataManager.DataManager.createServerMessage(DataManager.kt:183)` could you post this snippet of your code? It should be in red and it will take you to the method where the error is

Comment: Line 183 is `serverErrors.put("em_DailyDepositLimitIsBelowZero" , Resources.getSystem().getString(R.string.daily_deposit_limit))`. It's not in red, and I do not see where the error is

Comment: Does your String res file contain 'daily_desposit_limit'? , could you share your string res file ?

Comment: Yes my string res file contains 'daily_deposit_limit'. My strings.xml file looks like this 
```<resources>
...
<string name="daily_deposit_limit">The daily deposit limit you entered is below zero. Please enter a new amount.</string>
...
</resources>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `getString()` instead of `Resources.getSystem().getString()`